# variable and command substitution in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am a little confused about the substitution in TCL. Consider the following code:

```
set z [set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]
puts $z
```

The above code will give the result `This is a string within quotes within braces`

This part is clear, considering that variable **z** is set to the string `"This is a string within quotes within braces"`

As for the second command, after substitution, it should be like `puts "This is a string within quotes within braces"`

---

However, check the following code:

```
set z {[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]}
puts $z
```

Now the result is `[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]`. I don't quite understand this result here.

I'm aware that all the stuff grouped in curly braces have no substitution. So the variable **z** now should hold the value `[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]`.

But for the next line: `puts $z`, what I thought is that `$z` should be replaced by its value `[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]` and the command now looks like

```
puts [set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]
```

Why doesn't it just print `This is a string within quotes within braces`?

Comment: Braces prevent substitution from occurring. Did you try `puts {$z}` or `puts {[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]}`?

Comment: For your example `puts {$z}` or `puts {[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]}`. The result of those two are clear. What makes me confused is that variable **z** is set to the value of `[set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]`, so after substitution `puts $z` should now looks like `puts [set x "This is a string within quotes within braces"]`. But I understand it now. After the first substitution it won't be substituted again.

Comment: Tcl is a very simple language. All the syntax is contained in just 12 rules. Spend some time thinking about them, and Tcl becomes very powerful: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *contents* of the string retrieved from the variable (or the command) substitution are not reinterpreted by the Tcl language core; they just get given to the command that you are calling. Some commands do reinterpretation of their arguments (e.g, `eval` or `subst`) but `puts` does not: it just prints the value out to its destination channel (standard out by default). The commands that do reinterpretation are documented to do so.

---

When parsing `puts $z`, Tcl starts by looking at the first word, character by character. It doesn't find any Tcl metacharacters in there, so it gets a simple literal, `puts`. Then it looks at the second word and sees a Tcl variable substitution metacharacter followed by a letter, which is a proper variable substitution; the `$z` is *substituted* — i.e., replaced — by the characters read from the variable, but those characters in the input text are now parsed so there's nothing more to do.

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M31 - Rule 11 specifies that substitutions in Tcl are only done once, unlike Unix shells which keep substituting recursively.

Answer (score -1):

Found this answer in another SO question:

```
puts [subst $z]
```

This is a string within quotes within braces

Link:
[How to variable substitution when reading a file in Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452049/how-to-variable-substitution-when-reading-a-file-in-tcl)