# How to variable substitution when reading a file in Tcl

Tags: tcl

Here is my file name text and it has below contents

```
system
 {
host name $HOSTNAME
value 25

as 635
}
```

I am writing below code to read the file :

```
set HOSTNAME "NEw york"
set cf [open text r]
foreach line [split [read $cf] \n] {
puts $line
close $cf
```

When I do `puts $line` variable substitution for HOSTNAME is not done, how to do that ??

Answer (score 3):

Use the `subst` command:
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/subst.html

```
set HOSTNAME "New York"
set line {host name $HOSTNAME}

puts $line 
  --> "host name $HOSTNAME"
puts [subst $line]
  --> "host name New York"
```

Comment: `subst -nocommands $line`. To see why, put `[error]` into your file data and see it emit an error as it evaluates the tcl command. Consider now that the file might contain `[exec rm -rf /]`.

Comment: In 8.7, you'll be able to use `regsub -command` to do a nicer job of it, as you'll be able to control which variables are substituted and what with. (Typical examples include restriction to a whitelist or only allowing the user's environment variables.) Doing that sort of thing with just preparing the input to `subst` is annoyingly difficult to get right.

Comment: Thank you all .All worked

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want to support substituting `$HOSTNAME` and nothing else, use `string map`:

```
set HOSTNAME "NEw york"
set mapping [list "\$HOSTNAME" $HOSTNAME]
set cf [open text r]
foreach line [split [read $cf] \n] {
    puts [string map $hostname $line]
}
close $cf
```

The `string map` command is unreasonably great for doing any fixed set of replacements. While I know its implementation is internally very stupid, it has superb cache coherency and is exactly the sort of thing that CPU makers like to optimize for.